# Angular update failing on incorrectly "resolved" address

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

Morning all,

I am currently trying to update Angular from 7.1.0 to 8.3.23.

We have a custom package stored on our DevOps server. I am able to retrieve the package with npm when I delete the directory and '`npm install package-name`'. So far, all good.

The issue arises when I run '`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`' it stalls a few seconds later claiming a '`404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/package-name - Not found`'

Why does it divert to npmjs.org repo? There is no mention of this in the code anywhere.

My .npmrc file is fine, well in date and all correct. This has been updated as part of the tests to get this to work.

- node version 10.16.3
- Global Angular CLI - 8.3.23

Comment: Update command goes through your **package.json** and try to resolve them in **npmjs** directory. I had the exact same error. First uninstall that package from your project, update angular and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed Arcteezy's advice, removed the package, updated, reinstalled the package.

It works but it feels dirty and not professional especially for a clients project.